# Hsts in firefox and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, hsts

The web browsers store sts header but I dont know exactly where. Where does chrome and firefox store sts header? And can a browser turn off the hsts protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not aware of anyway of turning off this feature in any browser.

Chrome has a nice screen to handle HSTS settings (including the ability to remove cached versions) by typing this into the address bar: "chrome://net-internals/#hsts".

For Firefox you clear the history and "forget about this site".

For more details see here: http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers